Jenkins Coverage Plugin isn't publishing to GitHub
I have a .net test which generates a coverage report for my project, and it publishes the coverage report with Jenkins using the Coverage plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/coverage/).
However this plugin is supposed to seemingly automatically publish the coverage report back to the GitHub PR, which is what I want, via the Checks API. However there seems to be absolutely no documentation as to how this works, and the output I see in the logs is as follows:
[Coverage] Finished coverage processing - adding the action to the build...
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.

The pipeline steps reference (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/coverage/) only says this:
"the plugin automatically publishes a summary of the coverage report to corresponding SCM hosting platforms. For example, if you are using this feature for a GitHub organization project, the coverage summary will be published to GitHub through the Checks API".
There is no configuration to explicitly do this, and only a checkbox to suppress this behaviour. I don't know how to configure a 'checks publisher', but from what I read, the Coverage plugin should be doing this automatically. So the question is - how can I make this actually push the check back to my Github? It's an Enterprise server privately hosted, but that's not relevant since it's not attempting to post at all.
The job is checked out with pipeline checkout:
checkout scmGit(
                            branches: [[name: "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"]], 
                            extensions: [localBranch("${env.BRANCH_NAME}")], 
                            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'github-credentials', 
                            url: repoUrl]]
                        )

and is triggered from a PR using the Generic Webhook Plugin - although I'm not sure if this makes a difference. I'm not sure if the Checks API publisher is perhaps enshrined in another plugin that I'm not using, but I'm finding it really hard to tell despite checking all documentation and references I can find.
Tried to explicitly enclose the recordCoverage step (from the coverage plugin) in a withChecks() call:
withChecks('Coverage') {
                recordCoverage(
                    tools: [[
                    parser: 'COBERTURA', 
                    pattern: 'TestResults/*/coverage.cobertura.xml'
                ])
            }

but all that does is repeat the 'No suitable checks publisher found' log output.
